# Converting "42978.6736458333" varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar, converters

I've a `varchar` column with a value of `42978.6736458333` that I want to convert back to a proper `datetime`. I've searched quite a bit and tried many of the suggestions but I cannot seem to find one that works with the data I have.

I got this value from excel when I did a CONCATENATE of all the fields in the sheet to do an insert to my DB; the output of the datetime column looks like "42978.6736458333" (the cell originally contained "2017-08-31 16:10:03"). I tried formatting and various things in excel to no avail.

Here are a few examples of what I've tried:

```
Select
    convert(varchar(23), date, 112) DATE1,
    convert(datetime, '20160805') DATE2,
    convert(datetime, '2011-09-28 18:01:00', 120) DATE3,
    dateadd(second, 42978.6736458333 * 24*24*60, '1899-12-31') DATE4
From 
    [dbo].[trainingLog]
```

Results:

- DATE 1 = 42978.6736458333
- DATE 2 = 2016-08-05 00:00:00.000
- DATE 3 = 2011-09-28 18:01:00.000
- DATE 4 = 1947-01-25 11:16:01.000

For every result. DATE 2/3/4 don't count up even though the original datetime `varchar` increments.

For example, here are more `varchar` values:

```
42981.5092361111 
42982.7187615741 
42983.8171527778
```

The above attempts return a value/date, but it's the *same date* even though my varchar value increments.

I expect any datetime format. I really only want the month/day/year in any format.

Comment: Why are you storing a date and time, as a number, as a`varchar` in the first place? That's like a double faux pas. What date does `'42978.6736458333'` even represent?

Comment: It's not really mu desire to do so. That's how it came across from excel. The original cell contains "2017-08-31 16:10:03".

Comment: I think, you need to `delete` the inserted records in SQL, and `insert` again from excel, before you do concatenation in excel change the column format to text in excel i.e. `20170831` then it's easy to cast in SQL

Comment: @ShekarKola I did do that before concatenation; I tried text and all the date formats and got the same result.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do and why you think it is not working. `42978.6736458333` is already a datetime value, and `cast(42978.6736458333 as datetime)` gives `2017-08-31 16:10:03` like you expect. Casting the other values you are showing gives different datetime values as expected too, not the same value.

Comment: @GSerg **cast(42978.6736458333 as datetime)** gives me "2017-09-02 16:10:03.000" on all 418 distinct values for DATE1; that's my issue, each one of those returns a value, but it's the same value even though the varchar vale increments.

Comment: Try splitting date value into 3 new column (in excel). i.e. `=YEAR(CELL)`,  `=MONTH(CELL)`,  `=DAY(CELL)` and do the concatenation.

Comment: @ShekarKola I can do that, I was just hoping it would be a simple conversion in SQL.

Comment: @MicahC It sounds like you put the literal `cast(42978.6736458333 as datetime)` in the query instead of `cast(field_name as datetime)`.

Comment: There is no reference for SQL Engine to understand that the value `42978.6736` is made from particular date as it has been prepared outside the system, SQL just got string value during insert, i don't think we can force SQL engine to do casting `42978.6736` to date

Comment: @ShekarKola `datetime` has number of days since zero date (1900-01-01) before the decimal dot and time of day after the decimal dot as a fraction of full day. A `float` value is therefore castable to `datetime`.

Comment: @GSerg, Thanks for the clarification, good to know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`SELECT CAST(42978.6736458333 AS DATETIME)`

returns

`2017-09-02 16:10:03.000`

However SQL server uses 01/01/1900 as the epoch whereas your excel uses 30/12/1899 or 31/12/1899 as the epoch so it looks like you need to subtract 2 days off after you cast.

e.g.

`SELECT dateadd(d, -2, CAST(42978.6736458333 AS DATETIME) )`

returns

`2017-08-31 16:10:03.000`

From you comment I am not sure how you get your value as running

`SELECT CAST(42981.5092361111 AS DATETIME)`

returns for me

`2017-09-05 12:13:18.000`

Comment: It does; the problem is that it returns that same result for every varchar value, even though the varchar value increments up. More values to see:

>42981.5092361111

>42982.7187615741

>42983.8171527778

Comment: Sorry you are not being clear at all here, I can not understand what your issue is as you keep changing your question! I would recommend asking a clear concise question with what the issue actually is and what the xpected outcome is for a couple of examples. HTH

Comment: sorry still not clear, to me that picture looks correct, three different dates are returned as expected

Comment: @Rippo I get that same returned value as you do above. In my original question, all of the above examples provide a value, but it's the **same** value returned even though the DATE1 increments.

42978.**6736458333**>2017-09-02 16:10:03.000  & 42981.**5092361111**>2017-09-02 16:10:03.000

The varchar value changes but the returned value is the same. That's the issue.

Comment: @MicahC No it does not, like [I've shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537814/converting-42978-6736458333-varchar-to-datetime#comment101540414_57537914). [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537814/converting-42978-6736458333-varchar-to-datetime#comment101540442_57537814) your query.

Comment: @GSerg missed that before, and I am a moron.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an Excel time.  So:

```
select dateadd(minute, 42978.6736458333 * 24*60, '1899-12-31')
```

If you try to use seconds, you will get an overflow error.  If seconds are important, you can do:

```
select dateadd(day, floor(42978.6736458333), '1899-12-31') +
      dateadd(second, (42978.6736458333 % 1)*24*60*60, 0)
```

Comment: I only care about the day/month/year (in any format). The issue is that it returns the same value for every result even though the varchar (DATE1) incerements up: >42981.5092361111 >42982.7187615741 >42983.8171527778